# File encoding using ruby in windows

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have two files in a windows folder. Using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows) I found out that one file encoding is ANSI and another one is UTF-8.

However, If I open cmd or Powershell and try to get the encoding in IRB with the following code I get always "CP850":

```
File.open(file_name).read.encoding.name # => CP850
```

or

```
File.open(file_name).external_encoding.name # => CP850
```

Notepad++ also gives me that one file is ANSI and another is UTF-8.

How can I get the proper encoding using Ruby in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to tell what encoding a file is, but it's possible to make an educated guess.

When you open a file, ruby simply assumes it's encoded with the default 8-bit encoding (in your case CP850).

See [Detect encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074521/detect-encoding)

and [What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format) about ANSI